# why is my matplotlib boxplot appearing almost empty with only a few lines and half a dot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a car dataframe:

```
### Open and load the data ###
my_data_frame = pd.read_csv(data_file_pathname, sep=",", header=0)

### Print some instances in the console ###
print(my_data_frame.head())
print(my_data_frame.dtypes)

     model  year  price transmission  mileage fuelType  tax   mpg  engineSize
0    A1  2017  12500       Manual    15735   Petrol  150  55.4         1.4
1    A6  2016  16500    Automatic    36203   Diesel   20  64.2         2.0
2    A1  2016  11000       Manual    29946   Petrol   30  55.4         1.4
3    A4  2017  16800    Automatic    25952   Diesel  145  67.3         2.0
4    A3  2019  17300       Manual     1998   Petrol  145  49.6         1.0

model            object
year              int64
price             int64
transmission     object
mileage           int64
fuelType         object
tax               int64
mpg             float64
engineSize      float64
dtype: object
```

I have tried many ways to get a box and whiskers plot for the year column but they all failed. Now I am trying out the matplotlib boxplot function and it almost works but the boxplot won't really show. Here is the code I use:

```
my_data_frame.boxplot(column='year')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, there is a line and a dot but they seem out of the picture. Also, there are those weird lines on the y-axis that shouldn't be there. Anyone know what my problem is?

Comment: The provided sample produces an accurate boxplot. Can you provide a sample which reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that? I'm using my entire dataframe which has over 10000 rows.

Comment: Works fine for me as well. How do you import matplotlib? Tried ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt``` ?

Comment: Maybe some year values are not filled in? Maybe something like `my_data_frame[my_data_frame['year']>2000].boxplot(column='year')` could filter out the zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, was in my face the entire time. I had used the plt.figure() on a previous plot, so I was plotting my boxplot on this previous figure and it gave the result you saw.

By putting fig1 = plt.figure() for the first plot and fig2 = plt.figure() for the boxplot, the problem was solved.